# How to write generic code for union tables over years?

Tags: mysql, sql, hive, etl

I have an Hive ETL job where I have to extract data from yearly tables and union them. Don't ask why there is a separate table for each year (legacy systems and huge size).

Lets assume table names are table11, table12, . . ., table19

Now I can write query upto 'from' table19, but I want to write generic code, otherwise the code have to be updated every year. I believe one can't use wildcards in the 'from' clause, if I am correct. e.g. table20*

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

you can use prepared statement. So you can generate a query with **CONCAT** and then execute it.

```
-- SELECT CONCAT("insert into newtable select * from table",DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%y')) 
SELECT CONCAT(" select * from mysql.user") INTO @sql;
SELECT @sql;
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```